# Want to pass multiple associate array to view but one of the array has only one variable

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a controller that passing an array to a view. Unfortenetally, one of the fields `$data['c']` is not available in the view. It is having only a single variable.

```
function view() {
    $this->load->model('rateteacher_m');
    $rate_id= $this->uri->segment(4);
    $data['rows'] = $this->rateteacher_m->get_by_id($rate_id);
    $data['answers'] = $this->rateteacher_m->get_answer_by_question_id($rate_id);
    $data['c'] = $this->rateteacher_m->check_follow($rate_id,1) ;
    $this->load->view('specific_rateteacher_v', $data);
}
```

and my model...

```
function check_follow($rate_id,$user_id) {
    $count=mysql_num_rows($user_sql);
    $this->db->select('teacher_id, user_id');
    $this->db->from('teacher_follow');
    $q = $this->db->get();
    $result= $this->db->count_all_results();      
    $data['aa']=$result;
    return $data;
}
```

Then I tried to print all the content view:

```
<?php foreach($c as $r) : ?>
    <?php echo $r->aa; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I want to print the count in the view but it is not being done. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Hello! I am not seeing how $c is declared. Please show more code.

Comment: I think I have declared it here in controller function view. 
But I think I did it the wrong way. Can you guide me.

Comment: I am looking for $c = ...

Comment: If I return just the variable count in the model function then I can easily print it in the view but how to print it in the view ?

Comment: Sorry I am unaware of what $c looks like. Please post code for it.

Comment: @DavidChen `$c` is set by `$data['c']`. This is the way Codeigniter's views work.

Answer (score 0):

Your check_follow() method is returning an array with one item. `$this->db->count_all_results();` returns an integer. So if it returns 1, the method is returning `array('aa' => 1)` and nothing else.

Then in your view, you're trying to echo an object, but it's set to an array, so use `$c['aa']` instead or `$r->aa`.

Comment: so should I use a foreach in the view or not ??

Comment: Actually you can replace the foreach loop with `$c['aa']` if it's going to only be one item.

Comment: so in the model I return $result instead of the array then can I use the $result in the view along with the other $data object elements ?

Comment: Yes, I would do that. Because then $data['c'] in the controller becomes the same as $result. Then in the view $c is the same as $result and you can just echo $c only and don't need to mess with arrays for $c.

Comment: But I need to pass the other associative arrays also into the views.so I can't just pass that

Comment: You mean rows and answers? Those are getting passed too. You can get them with `$rows` and `$answers` in the view.

Answer (score 0):

this is a different angle. if your db results might be one or many, you can do this.

```
$query = $this->db->get( 'something' );

// its 1, so return the row()
if ( $query->num_rows() == 1 ) {
    return $query->row(); }

// its more then 1, return result() 
elseif( $query->num_rows() > 1 ) {
    return $query->result(); }

// no results, return false
else { return false ; }
```

will always return the db result as an object (no brackets needed to show in view)